# Animation of images producing unexpected, extra movement

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to create a function that moves images arranged in a radial layout around in a circle by swapping each one's position with their neighbor's position. The final effect is that the images are rotating around in a circle. The transform is activated when the S (counterclockwise) or D (clockwise) keys are pressed. I'm using an array to track the positions of the images and sending those coordinates to a function that actually does the transform.

The first rotation in either direction works fine. But any consecutive rotation in the same direction produces strange unwanted movement. In essence, with every new rotation the images all move inward towards the center of the circle before moving out again to take their final positions. The amount of inward motion gets worse with each key press.

Since I'm not allowed to attach an image to this email I have posted one here: 
http://i1266.photobucket.com/albums/jj532/ik_al/screencap.jpg

The image shows a series of screenshots to illustrate the phenomenon. Please note that the screenshots are all happening on ONE rotation.

Here's my XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="radialLayout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:radialLayout"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp">
<Grid Width="1024" Height="768"> 

    <MyNamespace:RadialPanel Margin="27,21,31,32" MouseWheel="RadialPanel_MouseWheel" x:Name="ImagePanel">
        <!--Must use same namespace declared above-->

      <!--Each image must have a unique name-->
        <Image Height="49" Name="image1" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image2" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_0841.JPG" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image3" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image4" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_0841.JPG" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image5" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image6" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_0863.JPG" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image7" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image8" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_1043.JPG" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image9" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image10" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_0863.JPG" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image11" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/profile.jpg" />
        <Image Height="49" Name="image12" Width="74" Source="/radialLayout;component/Images/IMG_0863.JPG" />

    </MyNamespace:RadialPanel>
```

And here is the function call and function implementation:

```
 for (int o = 0; o < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ImagePanel); o++)
            {
                Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ImagePanel, o);
                MyExtensions.MoveTo((Image)childVisual, lastPosition[o, 0], lastPosition[o, 1], ImagePanel.imageCoordinates[o, 0], ImagePanel.imageCoordinates[o, 1]);

            }

        public static void MoveTo(this Image target, double currentX, double currentY, double newX, double newY)
    {
        Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(target);
        var top = offset.Y;
        var left = offset.X;
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim1);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);
    }
```

Does anyone know what is causing this behavior or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation I finally figured out what I was doing wrong in my code.

I didn't understand that when using translateTranform the original position of the images is retained as the starting point for all consecutive transforms; I assumed it was updated to the last most current position. In addition, this starting point is always referenced by coordinates (0,0).

So to fix my animation problem I had to offset the **start** and **stop** positions of my images by subtracting each image's original position (before the first transform) from the current placement of the image on the screen (as stored in the array). For the first pass through these values will always add up to 0.

I was already completing this offset for the **stop** positions since it was necessary to get even the first transform to work. But as it turned out, this subtraction was needed to update the **start** positions as well.

In the code the original position of the image is stored in the **left** and **top** variables which reference the X and Y coordinates respectively.

Here's the part of the code that I changed:

```
        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(currentY-top, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(currentX-left, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

What was interesting about this error was that the resulting animation when all 12 images were transformed together was much more complex and interesting than it would have been if each image was moved individually. So there must be some interaction between how the image transforms are computed that produces emergent output. The output I was seeing made me think the solution was much more complex than it actually was.